# Calling components function from iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

I have an iframe in my window and I added new buttons to it with jquery. Before migrating to angular2, i was using parent.SampleFunction() to call parent's functions from iframe. Now parent is an angular component and it does not work.

```
export class AppComponent {

 // use jquery to find the iframe and put a button into it
 addButtonToIFrame() {
     ...
     let buttonHtml = "<button onClick='parent.SampleFunction()'></button>"
     ...
 }

 SampleFunction() {
  ...
 }
```

}

How should I change onclick function to access parent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Same Origin Iframe

You can safely access the window.parent object, so you just need to put your `SampleFunction` in the global `window` object.

```js
export class AppComponent {

 constructor(){
  (<any>window).SampleFunction= this.SampleFunction.bind(this);
 }

 // use jquery to find the iframe and put a button into it
 addButtonToIFrame() {
     ...
     let buttonHtml = "<button onClick='parent.SampleFunction()'></button>"
     ...
 }

 SampleFunction() {
  ...
 }
}
```

If you have multiple instances of same class and your `SampleFunction` deals with the component state, you might need to create random name for your `SampleFunction`.

You could also use the [`PostMessage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) which should be a more flexible alternative.

### PostMessage API

If you are dealing with iframe from another domain, you can use the PostMessage API :

**script inside iframe**

```js
window.parent.postMessage({foo:"foo"});
```

**component inside parent**

```js
export class AppComponent {

 @HostListener("window:message",["$event"])
 SampleFunction($event:MessageEvent) {
  if (event.origin !== "protocol://my-expected-domain.tdl:port")
    return;
  console.log($event.data)// {foo:"foo"}
 }

}
```

Of course you have to check the `event.origin` against the actual domain of the iframe.

Comment: Hi I'm using your above method but i'm getting error cross domain scripting can you update your answer to allow cross domain scripting i shell be very thankful to you

Comment: I added an example for postMessage API.

Comment: @n00dl3 this is very helpful.  In my case the child site is an Angular app, but the parent is not. Any pointers how to create a listener (like your @HostListener) in the parent using vanilla javascript?  For context I don't have total control of the parent page.  I can provide custom scripts (which I'm using to insert the iframe, for example), so I'm hopeful I can create a listener too.

Comment: @mike_butak You can find plenty of useful informations on mdn : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#The_dispatched_event
You just need to use `window.addEventListener("message",function(){})` on parent page

Comment: @n00dl3 Thank you!